# at least vs at least in part

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

Lost marks. And in exams, with time pressure and stress you lose it bad. It is worst when you know that how easy it was if the English (language) was understood right. The passage was research based. A question goes like this,

> "which of the following according to xyz, is at least in part
>   responsible for bla bla bla..."

Eyeballed and I quickly circled "least responsible", tricky as it is, and doomed!

There's another usage of at least in part, [reference here.](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/balance-maintained-least-part-endolymph-fluid-inner-ear-spinning-displaces-fluid-causing-d-q5784853)

> "Our balance is maintained, at least in part, by the endolymph fluid
>   in the inner ear."

I want to know how/why it is used in different materials, either as "at least in part" or "in part at least".

Answer (score 1):

"at least in part" means partly or partially, or perhaps completely

OELD definition of "in part"

> To some extent though not entirely. ‘the cause of the illness *is at
>   least in part* psychological’

Comment: Not quite: "at least in part" means "either partially or fully". A disease that is "at least in part psychological" could be partly physical and partly psychological, or it might be completely psychological.

Comment: @Amadan what about the other usage?  In psrt at least? This short phrase (u call it a phrase??) seem to be used in two orders.

Comment: @bonCodigo They are equivalent.